# Dictionary not populating correctly

Tags: python, pygame

I've encountered an issue with my code that I simply cannot figure out.

As per the below section of code:

After creating a 2nd dictionary `(worldmap)` in the `Generate_Game_World` class, the HQ location is stored in

```
self.worldmap[HQLOCATIONX,HQLOCATIONY]["Region_Type"] = "HQ"
```

However, after doing so it seems to fill up the entire array with the "HQ" value as seen in the test window. I simply cannot figure out why this is happening.

```
import pygame
from tkinter import *

test = Tk ()
test.geometry = ("640x480")

pygame.init()

WORLDSIZE = 499
HQLOCATIONX = int(WORLDSIZE/2)
HQLOCATIONY = int(WORLDSIZE/2)

class Generate_Game_World ():

    regionData = {"Region_Type" : "None", 
                  "Region_Level" : 0}

    def __init__(self, mapSize):
        self.mapSize = mapSize

    def main (self):
        # creates 2d map
        self.worldmap = {(x,y) : self.regionData for x in range(self.mapSize) for y in range (self.mapSize)}

        # Sets the HQ to worldmap(249,249)
        self.worldmap[HQLOCATIONX,HQLOCATIONY]["Region_Type"] = "HQ"

        # checks worldmap(0,0) --> (10,10) for its Region Type
        for x in range (10):
            for y in range (10):
                label = Label (text=self.worldmap[x,y]["Region_Type"]).grid(row = x, column=y)

class Game (object):
    def main (self, screen):
        gameworld = Generate_Game_World(WORLDSIZE)     
        gameworld.main()

        while 1:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

            test.mainloop()
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
    Game().main(screen)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your dictionary values are references to the *one* class-attribute `regionData`.

You want to create *copies* instead:

```
self.worldmap = {(x,y): self.regionData.copy() for x in range(self.mapSize) for y in range (self.mapSize)}
```

This uses the [`dict.copy()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) to create a shallow copy instead; this is enough as the values of `Generate_Game_World.regionData` are mere strings and these are immutable so are safe to be shared.

You could also use a dictionary literal to create a new dictionary from scratch; you don't seem to be using `self.regionData` anywhere else so inlining is a possibility:

```
self.worldmap = {(x,y): {"Region_Type" : "None", "Region_Level" : 0} 
                 for x in range(self.mapSize) for y in range (self.mapSize)}
```

Last but not least, did you mean to use the `None` singleton instead of a string `"None"` perhaps?

Comment: The code I provided is just a snippet from the larger part of the project, isolating the area that was giving me trouble.

The keys are used to display tiles as they are referenced. None.png, HQ.png etc.

Comment: @Jess: Right, in which case you want to create copies of the dictionary. If your `regionData` dictionary contains other mutable values, use `copy.deepcopy()` instead.

Comment: I've wasted more than 2 hours trying to figure this out, and you've helped me save many many more hours. Thanks :)